# Forbidden Message when trying to delete Sharepoint item with Javascript and Rest

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, sharepoint

I can get items from Sharepoint list with AngularJS but when i try to delete them with my function i get a forbidden message.

This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://spserver/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items(" + MyId +")",
   type: "POST",
   headers: {
    "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
    "IF-MATCH": "*",
    "X-HTTP-Method": "DELETE"
   },
   success: function (data) {                          
    alert("Deleted Successfully.");
   },
   error: function (error) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
   }
  });
```

Comment: Code looks fine. However, check the following things..

1. Check if the Request Digest value is accompanied with the request using fiddler

2. Even with the Request Digest you are getting the issue, check if you have enough permissions to delete item. Because 'Forbidden' indicates the Authorization issue.

3. If the above 2 validations are passed and still you are getting the error, toggle 'type' with 'method' - It shouldn't be a problem but check...

Comment: 1 - i have enough permissions to delete item in the list & the error is 403 Forbiden 
2 - i have a value in the X-RequestDigest with Fiddler2